# Linking EXE files from IBM WCM not working. Linking any Images, PDFs works fine

Tags: websphere-portal, wcm, lotus-wcm, ibm-wcm

We have a WCM COntent Library. Inside the "Components" area, we have created an EXE folder as seen below. This exe folder contains exe files.

[image]

Now, whenever I am trying to place a link to the `.exe` files on any HTML page, Link is generated but when viewed in browser, it throws 404 error.
[image]

As seen the HREF value seems fine but not sure why this doesn't works. Also When i create a link to any other Components ( Images: JPG, GIF, PDFs) the links work perfectly normal. Why this is NOT working for EXE files ?

Answer (score 1):

Use Insert link button in Presentation template to create a link to the File component having exe file.
Firebug element

```
<a href="/wps/wcm/myconnect/5f6187f3-1b17-43d8-87d1-fbbc19de1863/cfg.exe?MOD=AJPERES&ContentCache=NONE&CACHE=NONE&CVID=laxoBjd&CVID=laxoBjd">test</a>
```

Same gets generated in template as well

```
<a title="" target="" href="/wps/wcm/myconnect/5f6187f3-1b17-43d8-87d1-fbbc19de1863/cfg.exe?MOD=AJPERES&CVID=laxoBjd&useDefaultText=1&useDefaultDesc=0&CVID=laxoBjd">test</a>
```

Portal is 8.5

Comment: Thank you for the much awaited reply!. However this doesn't seems to help. I have used Insert Link button to create the links to EXE files but NO luck till now. Also, the link is generated the same as you have mentioned but still when viewed on a browser, it doesn't works

Comment: what is the portal version?

Comment: How to check the Portal Version ? Apologies, Im new to this WCM